# Inserting an element (div) before a centered element (div)

Tags: html

I have a fixed width div with centered text

```
 --------Centered Text--------
```

I would like to append another div that has right aligned text right before the centered div.

```
 This is Centered Text------
```

**EDIT**: 
I updated the jsfiddle code so it isn't left in such a disoriented state.

I was trying many different approaches and ended up posting a messy example.  The code below shows what I am trying to do.

```html
<div class="text-entry" style="
                          display:flex;
                          justify-content: center;
                          background-color:grey;
                          ">
                           
<div style="display:inline-block; width:100px; text-align:right; background-color:red;">My-</div>
   <div style="background-color:white; ">Text</div>
   <div style="display:inline-block; width:100px;"></div>
   
</div>

<!--- ------------------- -->

<div class="text-entry" style="background-color:grey;text-align:center;">

   <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:white; ">
 Text
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is what is the proper way to implement this instead of using two inline-blocks of fixed width?

*Excuse my lack of skills.  I am doing this as a hobby and not professionally.  Thank you for the help.  I have googled before coming here.

Comment: Your use of different `display` properties seems a little random. Maybe you should educate yourself on that first?

Comment: I was messing around with different ideas and left the jsfiddle in a half finished state!   

My idea was to make the parent div a flex container and align the children items centered.  

The first text would be an inline block of fixed width with right aligned text.
The 2nd text would be an inline.  
The 3rd box would be inline block of fixed width same as the 1rst one with no text.


It would look like this function like this.


http://jsfiddle.net/91nt75kv/

That is why I had random display properties.  I didn't know the correct way to do it!